# When I run "Heroku ps" I am not on unicorn but on the standard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, procfile

Running Heroku ps is not giving me the expected outcome of `bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb` but the regular `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`, despite my having a Procfile with the following:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

and the appropriate unicorn.rb file setup.

When I run `Heroku run bash` the Procfile is not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - just needed to change my gemfile as follows:

WHEN GETTING THE ERROR:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sinatra', '>= 1.3.0', :require => nil
end
```

ERROR FIXED WITH:

```
gem 'sinatra', require: false
```